# Firestore: How to change mCollection.orderBy with viewpager (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I want to change filter/orderBy with viewpager, and my viewpager in MainActivity like this

```
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPagerAdapter= new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new HomeFragment(),"Recent"); // `new HomeFragment()` should be in `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
    viewPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new HomeFragment(),"Score"); // `new HomeFragment()` should be in `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
```

I have default `(position 0)` query at `onCreateView (HomeFagment)` like this

```
mQuery = mCollection.orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
```

i've tried with this and orderBy didn't change to "score"

```
viewPagerMain.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                switch (position){
                    case 0 :
                        mQuery = mPostsCollection.orderBy("time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
                        mAdapter.refresh();
                        break;
                    case 1 :
                        mQuery = mPostsCollection.orderBy("score", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
                        mAdapter.refresh();
                        break;
            }

        });

final PagedList.Config mConfig = new PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .setPrefetchDistance(2)
                .setPageSize(3)
                .build();

FirestorePagingOptions<Post> options = new FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<Post>()
                .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                .setQuery(mQuery, mConfig, Post.class)
                .build();
```

Comment: What's wrong with the shared code? Please also
 add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: How are `mQuery` and `mAdapter` related? Right now you create a new `mQuery`, and it seems unlikely that `mAdapter` automatically knows about that. More likely, you'll need to create a new adapter for the new query and set that to your view to get the data from the new query.